# How can i validate a textbox which is inside listview so that it may not allow null value in runtime?

Tags: asp.net, listview, exception

I have a listview which consist of **Taxinreal,Taxinpercent,Amount,Netamount,Datetakenplace** textboxes. All of these fields are contained in **tblexpenses** table in my database. Now what i want is  in  insert mode of listview, i want **Amount** textbox not to be null i.e. if a user doesn't supply any value in **Amount** textbox in runtime, then a message must occur which states that "**Amount TextBox cannot be empty"**. How can i do this??? Right Now if i don't place value in **Amount** textbox in runtime then the following error occurs.**"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Amount', table 'dbbilling.dbo.tblexpenses'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.The statement has been terminated."**. 
(P.S. In database i have made my **Amount** column to not allow null values)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert null values in your table if you want to insert as follows

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tableName (field1, field2, field3) 
  VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", someVar ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Else You can check before inserting the value in if confition
Like

```
 if((String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAmount.text))
 {

 }
 else
 {

 }
```

Comment: i figured it out......it can be done simply by a required field validator as in other aspx pages